# vba PULL function speed up

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the PULL function (http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.excel.worksheet.functions/msg/e249f6c074a3adfd?pli=1) which is like INDIRECT except that it can reference a closed workbook.

The PULL function works fine, except that it creates an excel instance every time it is called and that makes calculation of the workbook with many calls extremely slow.

Is there a way to re-write this function such that it will run significantly faster?

Comment: You could edit the function to make the xlapp variable static: then it would always use the one instance.  You'll be left with no clean way to remove it automatically though, so depends on how much you need the additional performance.

Comment: Tim - I don't know how you do that with a UDF.  I tried pulling the xlapp object reference out of the UDF and making it a public variable in the code module but this didn't work; the object needed to be recreated every time the UDF was called.  My understanding of the UDF was that you cannot modify global variables in the code modules, or if you do, they don't persist.

Comment: You don't need global variables. Just make the xlapp a static variable in the UDF

Answer (score 2):

Pull is SLOW. It's intentionally nonvolatile. It could be improved by making the Application instance effectively static (I'd make it a private, module-level variable), but that could lead to reentrance issues which I didn't want to tackle. At that point, it'd be better to make the guts a class and the udf merely a wrapper around one of the methods, again something I didn't want to tackle.

If you have many formulas calling pull and most refer to different workbooks, you may be better off using Laurent Longre's MOREFUNC.XLL add-in, which provides a function named INDIRECT.EXT. It also uses a second Excel application instance to dereference ranges in closed workbooks, but because it's an XLL rather than VBA, it may be a bit faster.

OTOH, if you're referring to multiple cells in a few workbooks, at the cost of storage you could use pull as an array formula, pulling in large ranges in a single call.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you do not wish to use:

```
='C:\Full\Path\To\ExcelFile\[Book1.xls]Sheet1'!$B$2
```

Comment: Yes, my file paths are dynamic.  I have data in files like '4-1-XX.xls' where XX is the year.

Comment: How about `"4-1-" & TEXT(A1,"yy") & ".xls"`?

Comment: How do you make that work?  Can you give a full formula example?  I don't understand how you can make the path dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they may be opening a workbook every time for some reason when using the Execute4Macro. I haven't use it much but maybe you could experiment with it and try something directly like this (instead of using the persons function):

```
arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
        wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
```

As found at http://www.exceltip.com/st/Read_information_from_a_closed_workbook_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/473.html

There are functions that work with closed workbooks so maybe you could use something similar to that too, like, SUMPRODUCT, I believe can operate on a closed workbook, or maybe one of the Database functions.

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do so you'll have to be more specific if you want a more specific answer.

Try some of the solutions offered here:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=14353

Comment: Basically I need a version of INDIRECT that can read from a closed workbook.  In my main workbook, I use the CONCATENATE function to assemble the workbook name, sheet, and cells I need to reference dynamically.  The problem is that INDIRECT only works with open workbooks and I don't want to have to open hundreds of workbooks just to get my main workbook to update.

Answer (score -1):

A small macro to change the LINK entry is all that is required :

```
ActiveWorkbook.ChangeLink Name:="C:\Temp\DeleteMe1.xlsx", NewName:= _
        "C:\Temp\DeleteMe.xlsx", Type:=xlExcelLinks
```